# I have slope raster and that is categorized with slope in percentage(%) but my script not successful

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I have slope raster and that is categorized with slope in percentage(%)
my condition is

```
if                 
             slope <= 1     then m = 0.2    
         1 < slope <= 3     then m = 0.3     
         3 < slope <= 5     then m = 0.4    
         5 < slope          then m = 0.5
```

Here "slope" is raster data and m is other variable that change as per slope percentage.

Is used raster calculator in ArcGIS 10.1 with script shown as below:

```
Con((("Slope" <= 1),0.2)  |  (("Slope" <= 3  &  "Slope"  > 1),0.3) | 
    (("Slope" <= 5  &  "Slope"  > 3),0.4) | (("Slope" > 5),0.5))
```

But it is not successful.

Comment: Could you say how it is not successfull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would write this to reduce the number of tests :

```
Con("Slope" <= 1 , 0.2 , Con("Slope" <= 3 , 0.3 , Con("Slope" <= 5, 0.4 , 0.5)))
```

Note that you need to write several Con() because "|" is only used to test booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a reclassify?

Other option it would be to read the raster like array and then perform the changes in the sense you want.